# How to test to make sure code works in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have written a regular expression in Notepad++ using PHP. I want to enter some test strings to see if it works or if it needs edited. How can I do this in Notepad++?

I tried the Run menu item (F5), but it's just asking for a filename. When I chose the filename that contains the code and click Run, it asks which program to open it with. I chose Notepad++, then nothing happens.

Comment: The "program to run" may be looking for `php.exe`, which is what would interpret PHP code.

Comment: Is there a way to test the code in Notepad++ without having to run it through a different program?

Comment: I doubt there's a way to test PHP code without using a PHP interpreter, no.  Why?  What actual problem are you trying to solve?  Why not use an actual IDE for PHP development?

Comment: That works for me. I suppose I don't understand the benefit of Notepad++ if I have to use the actual program to test it.

Comment: Well, Notepad++ is a text editor.  It's for editing text file.  It's pretty feature-rich as far as text editors go, even so far as to include basic functionality for writing code.  But it's not a PHP interpreter, nor has it ever claimed to be.

Comment: I was expecting that since the language is available in the program that it could provide feedback on if code was correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest xampp packet, very simple to use - it is all explained on apachefriends.org, but all you need is a php packet (its a part of xampp too) and to write "running php in notepad++" in google then follow the first video. Then you will be able to run simple php code from notepad++.